# GROUP BY without specific column

Tags: sql, group-by, aggregate-functions, having

I try to do this, but it won't let me.

My Table (MSSQL):

```
+----------+--------+---------------------+----------+-------+------------+
| parentid | okeyno |      okeyname       | okeydata | recid | okeydouble |
+----------+--------+---------------------+----------+-------+------------+
|     1357 |      1 | WINZERKE01_TESTFELD |      123 |  1486 |          0 |
|     1360 |      1 | WINZERKE01_TESTFELD |      456 |  1488 |          0 |
|     1362 |      1 | WINZERKE01_TESTFELD |      789 |  1492 |          0 |
|     1361 |      1 | WINZERKE01_TESTFELD |      789 |  1490 |          0 |
|     1358 |      1 | WINZERKE01_TESTFELD |      123 |  1484 |          0 |
|     1377 |      1 | WINZERKE01_TESTFELD |      999 |  1485 |          0 |
+----------+--------+---------------------+----------+-------+------------+
```

What you can see, is that there are several entrys with the same okeyname.
I now want only the parentid of the row, where there is no dublicate okeydata.

in this case the result should be "1360" and "1377".

Now this is what I've trying to do:

`SELECT 
    parentid
FROM 
    objkeys
WHERE 
    okeyname = 'WINZERKE01_TESTFELD'
GROUP BY 
    okeydata
HAVING 
    COUNT(okeydata) = 1`

But it always wants, that I include parentid into the GROUP BY.
But I don't want this.
How could I solve that problem?

Thanks.

Comment: You say you only want the parentid, 1360, so why do you select all columns (*)?

Answer (score 2):

Since you *know* that the result only represents a single row, there should be no issue with applying any of the aggregates which return their input if only given one input row. E.g. `MIN`, `MAX`, `SUM`:

```
SELECT 
    okeydata, MIN(parentid) as parentid
FROM 
    objkeys
WHERE 
    okeyname = 'WINZERKE01_TESTFELD'
GROUP BY 
    okeydata
HAVING 
    COUNT(okeydata) = 1
```

Comment: Ok, sorry, this doesn't seem to work that well.
What if I now habe another row with okeydata "999" and want to let me show ALL unique okeydata fields?

Comment: @Baris Kilic: That should still work. Damien groups by `okeydata` so there is one result row per `okeydata`. He then limits this to `okeydata` for which only one record exists. So when selecting `MIN(parentid)` per result row, he gets *the* parentid per row. Why do you say it doesn't work?

Comment: @BarisKilic - that should be fine. The only variation I think you might want to make to the above would be if you're querying across multiple `okeyname` values - in that case, you'd want to add that column to the `GROUP BY` clause also. But that same issue was in your original query.